# Android Studio cannot show cpp files in project navigator after latest update

Tags: android-studio, cmake

Last time I was careless to updated Android Studio to the latest realease:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 27, 2021
```

Then all the cpp files disappeared in my project navigator in Android session:
[image]

I can only see the jni folder and a `jni.cpp` file in Project session:
[image]
and all other cpp files in `cpp` folder missed. I have tried to delete all `CMakeCache.txt` files in directory `.externalNativeBuild` but it does not work, my gradle is as follows:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../../../CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

And the building system still compiles these cpp files. Who can help me out? or should I downgrade to original version?

Comment: I am facing the same, did u get any solution so far. ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not quite answering the exact question, but I found if you want to just show your JNI files again in Android Studio do this -

Create an empty Android_dummy.mk file, then add this to your gradle:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path file('src/main/jni/Android_dummy.mk')
    }
}
```

I needed this as I build the libraries outside AS manually with ndk-build

Answer (score 0):

to add CPP folder again.

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
```

[image]